# Passing external arguments to sbt jar (created via sbt-assembly)

Tags: scala, sbt, logback, sbt-assembly

I have created an assembly jar project based on https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly and wish to load "logback.xml" and "application.conf" externally which overrides both the default files packaged in the fatjar.

Something similiar to this

```
  java -jar XXX.jar -Dlogger.resource=prod-logger.xml -Dconf.resource=application.conf
```

Very similar to what play provides http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger

Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

[Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) says:

> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath.
> 4. If neither file is found, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

So if you want to externally configure this, you need to have access to the classpath. [`-jar` section on java - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#jar) says:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

This includes `-cp` options. So what you are stuck with is using `java -cp XXX.jar:somedir Main` and put your configurations in `somedir`.